# citus write activity after ingestion is completed

Tags: postgresql, citus

I have a citus cluster of 1 coordinator node (32 vcores , 64 GB RAM) and 6 worker nodes (4 cores , 32 GB RAM each).

After performing ingestion of data using the following command where chunks_0 directory contains 300 files having 1M record each:

```
find chunks_0/ -type f | time xargs -n1 -P24 sh -c "psql -d citus_testing -c \"\\copy table_1 from '/home/postgres/\$0' with csv HEADER;\""
```

I notice that after the ingestion is done, there is still a write activity occurring on the worker nodes at smaller rate (was around 800MB/sec overall during ingestion, and around 80-100MB/sec after ingestion) for a certain time.
I'm wondering what is citus doing during this time?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not run any queries in said time period, I do not think Citus is responsible for any writes. It's possible that PostgreSQL ran autovacuum. You can check the PostgreSQL logs in the worker nodes and see for yourself.